# Forecasting/predicting distribution of customer spend

Tags: distributions, forecasting, prediction

This is my first question, so I hope I get it right. I can define the starting point as well as the desired outcome , but the how is a mystery to me at the moment. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

**Problem:**

- *What I have:*

I have a data set of customer numbers and all their financial transaction details for a 12-month period.

I can easily generate the customer spend distribution/histogram for that period 
well as calculate percentiles using SAS.

The histogram resembles a Gamma or Weibull distribution - the vast majority of customers spends very little (first bar is the tallest), and the frequencies drop sharply with a long tail to the right.

- *What I need:*

I would need to **predict the spend distribution for the next 12 month period**.

I know the customer numbers are growing steadily (approx. linearly), thus one naive approach would be to predict the number of customers and then apportion them into the existing spend brackets of the previous 12-month spend distribution. However, this assumes zero change in customers' spend behavior.

What would be a better way to approach this?

In terms of tools I have SAS Enterprise Guide and R (and Excel of course).

**My background:**

I have a background in applied mathematics and I work in the area of business analytics. My statistics skills are VERY rusty as I specialised in another area and moved to analytics only fairly recently. The last time I did anything statistical beyond t-tests and linear regression was at university almost 10 years ago. I have an understanding of many statistical concepts, but little experience in applying them so far.

Hope the above allows for people to come up with potential solutions.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: One problem you have: many spending patterns show an annual cycle, but with data from only one year, identifying this is a challenge. Perhaps you could extract something if you had a strong prior expectation that this annual cycle should follow a specific pattern (e.g. sinusoidal)?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. The issue is that I do not have data before May 2016. I understand this is not optimal, but can I still achieve my goal? With compromises in accuracy I guess.